# How long my android BLE device will advertise once I start advertising? And is there a way to increase the duration?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to create an advertiser in my android application. I want to advertise it for indefinite time.

Answer (score 1):

You can advertise for an indefinite time by passing a value of 0 to the `setTimeout()` method. Have a look at the links below for more information:-

- [Android Advertise Settings Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseSettings.Builder#setTimeout(int))
- [Advertising a BLE Device Tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/android/example/30767/advertising-a-ble-device)
- [Bluetooth Low Energy on Android](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/bluetooth-low-energy-on-android-part-1/)

I hope this helps.